# How to add jemalloc to existing rails server using rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, jemalloc

how to add jemalloc in a working ruby on rails server?We installed ruby using rvm.

`Rails version:5.2
 Ruby version:2.5.1`

I tried

```
ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS']"
```

whose output i got as

```
-lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

I saw an article [Lower Memory Usage of your Rails App with Jemalloc](https://bubblin.io/blog/jemalloc) but its using rbenv

Answer (score 6):

I managed to add jemalloc using the following steps:

Install the Jemalloc library, preferably using your distro's package manager. (apt, pacman, brew, etc.):

```
# For instance, on Ubuntu:
sudo apt install libjemalloc-dev
```

Reinstall the currently installed ruby version with a compilation flag to include Jemalloc support:

```
rvm reinstall 2.6.6 -C --with-jemalloc
```

*Older versions of ruby used the compilation flag syntax `-with-jemalloc` (with a single dash) but Ruby 2.6 and up use `--with-jemalloc` (with a double dash).*

Then check that Jemalloc support has been added properly:

```
# For ruby >= 2.6:
ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS']"
# For ruby < 2.6:
ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS']"
```

It should output something like:

```
-lpthread -ljemalloc -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Comment: It needs two dashes in the "rvm reinstall" command --with-jemalloc.  Also beware - many comment platforms automatically replace two dashes with an mdash - which caused me an hour of confusion since it looks similar :)

ALSO - the command to test has changed, you need to use MAINLIBS instead of LIBS

Answer (score 5):

Updates to @ste20654 answer

For me this command

```
ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS']"
```

returned

```
-lm
```

What worked is this

```
ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS']"
```

OR

```
ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['SOLIBS']"
```

which returned ( if ruby is correctly compiled with jemalloc )

```
-lz -lpthread -lrt -lrt -ljemalloc -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Comment: Valid as 2021 with ruby 2.7, the popular answer did not display the ljemalloc but this option did